# I'm adding an Entity (Category) as a property in another Entity (Product). System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

In my API project, there is the entity Category as below:

```
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }                
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Category(string id, string title)
```

And the Entity Product where Category is a property:

```
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Título é obrigatório.")]
    [MaxLength(60, ErrorMessage = "Este campo deve conter enre 3 e 60 caracteres.")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Este campo deve conter enre 3 e 60 caracteres.")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(1024, ErrorMessage = "Este campo deve ter no máximo 1024 caracteres")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Este campo é obrigatório")]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "O preço deve ser maior que zero")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int AvailableQuantity { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Este campo é obrigatório")]
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
```

This is the Create Method in the ProductController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Product>> Create([FromBody] Product model)
    {
        var category = _context.Categories.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.CategoryId);

        if (category == null)
            return Ok("Categoria informada não existe");


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _product.GenerateId(model);
            var product = new Product(model.Id, model.Title, model.Description, model.Price, model.CategoryId, category);
            _context.Products.Add(product);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return product;
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }
```

When I try to create a new Product I receive the error message as below:

System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 280CF21D
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior) at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryTable`1.Create(IUpdateEntry entry) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryStore.ExecuteTransaction(IList`1 entries, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 updateLogger) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryDatabase.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entries, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at TesteAPI.Controllers.ProductsController.Create(Product model) in C:\Users\tcho3\source\repos\TesteAPI\TesteAPI\Controllers\ProductsController.cs:line 93 at lambda_method56(Closure , Object ) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: Can you post  _product.GenerateId(model); too, pls?

Comment: see:  public void GenerateId(Product product)
        {
            product.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "").ToUpper().Substring(0, 8);
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix model

```
public class Category 
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }                
    public string Title { get; set; }
    .....

   public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set}
}
```

You don't need a special constructor for Product too since you are using Product as a model

fix your action

```
  public async Task<ActionResult<Product>> Create([FromBody] Product model)
    {
     
//---------- I don't think that you really need this

  var category = _context.Categories.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.CategoryId);
        if (category == null)  return Ok("Categoria informada não existe");

//---------

 //would be enough
    if (model.category == 0)  return Ok("Categoria informada não existe");



        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _product.GenerateId(model);
            _context.Products.Add(model;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return model;
        }
        else
        {
            .....
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay, on this way, the object Category will be not necessary anymore. Right?

Comment: Yes you don't need it if you have a saved categoryId. You only need it if you want to add new product with new category. It is usually used for auto generated keys. So you don't need it too. I don't know why you selected Id as a string. Integer would be much more effective and convenient

Comment: Yes, in this way it'll run. But for other actions I'd like to use the Include as below and for that I need to pass the object category. var products = await _context.Products.Include(x => x.Category).AsNoTracking(). Where(x => x.Category.Id == id).ToListAsync();

About the id as string, I'm genereting that as below:
 public void GenerateId(Product product)
        {
            product.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "").ToUpper().Substring(0, 8);
        }

Comment: Your question is about add new, and my code too. If you want to use include for select, use it. It has nothing to do with adding  the new one.

Answer (score 0):

yes because the Category already exist in the database so that the category to be related to the product you just need to pass the `CategoryId`  when you create the Product like the Following :

```
var product = new Product(model.Id, model.Title, model.Description, model.Price, model.CategoryId);
```

no need to pass `category` object.

Comment: Yes, in this way it'll run.
But for other actions I'd like to use the Include as below and for that I need to pass the object category.

var products = await _context.Products.Include(x => x.Category).AsNoTracking().
                Where(x => x.Category.Id == id).ToListAsync();

Comment: @GustavoKaicCorrêa if you mean by "But for other actions" is an other action method; you can do that flawlessly ( in the add operation the EF just need the categoryId to construct the relationship).

Comment: so you can use the query i already posted to you in the add operation and you can use the query you already posted to me in the comment , to retrieve the product with it's related category information.

Comment: Understand. Thankyou very much!

Comment: @GustavoKaicCorrêa if I answered  your question you can flagged it as Answered